Overriding HashMap.toString() in string interpolation contexts
I am trying to create a subclass of HashMap with its own string representation. I figured that I just needed to override toString() in the subclass:
class Foo extends HashMap {
  String toString() {
    "foo"
  }
}

This works, insofar as I can do (new Foo()).toString() and it returns the string foo. However, in a string interpolation context (or when using as String), the toString implementation of HashMap seems to rule:
Foo test = new Foo()
test["abc"] = 123

println "${test.toString()}"  // Prints: foo
println "${test}"             // Prints: [abc:123]
println (test as String)      // Prints: [abc:123]

I'm curious why this happens and what -- if anything -- I can do to get around it?

Could you use composition instead of inheritance? Ie: could Foo contain a map which you delegate to, instead of trying to extend a map?

Not really; in this case, I need a subclass of HashMap in order to satisfy type constraints from dependencies.

It happens, because FormatHelper.write has a dedicated branch for Map instances.

Here is a unit test that passes:
class JustTest extends Specification {
    @TupleConstructor
    class X<A,B> extends HashMap<A,B> {
        String toString() {
            return "CUSTOM".toString()
        }
        <T> T asType(Class<T> clazz) {
            return switch (clazz) {
                case String -> this.toString() as T
                default -> throw new GroovyCastException("Error casting X to " + clazz.name)
            }
        }
    }
    def "Test"() {
        setup:
            X<Integer, Integer> x = new X()
            x[100] = 200
        expect:
            assert x.toString() == "CUSTOM"
            assert (x as String) == "CUSTOM"
    }
}

However it doesn't work when used inside a GString: "$x". In such case you will need to first force it to be string: "${x.toString()}".
See this question for more info.
